# How to set up Networking and DHCP in windows server 2012 inside VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, dhcp, windows-server-2012

Background:

Three operating systems are installed inside VirtualBox:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows 8 Pro
- Windows 8 Enterprise

So, I want to set up the Server 2012 R2 as Domain Controller, DHCP, and DNS to manage the other two OS. Which networking adapter should be selected in the virtual machine settings in these two circumstances:

1. Virtual Machines only network.
2. Virtual Machine with external network/internet access.

And how should you set up the Domain Controller and DHCP?

Edits:
How do you configure DHCP if you set all vm adapters as internal? What are the adapter configuration? And what are the DHCP configuration for windows server?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information.  Do you want your machines to be able to access an external network, like the Internet?  If so, how do you plan to allow them to access that network?  If not, setting them all to the same `Internal` network should work.

Comment: Again I ask, are you expecting these machines to be able to access an external network, like the Internet?  If not, you can just setup your DHCP server with a static IP address and have it serve addresses in one of the RFC1918 ranges.  You're question is very broad, perhaps reading the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732584.aspx) might be helpful?

Comment: Well for now I just want to set up a basic network. So, I just need to add the other two operating system to domain controller and those OSs should get IP from that DHCP server. To connect to external network, can we just add an extra virtual adapter?

Comment: Ok, I would say `Internal` network is what you want.   As I said before give your DC a static IP address, something like `192.168.1.1` and then setup the DHCP server to serve up addresses in that subnet.

Comment: @heavyd Okay, when setting the ethernet adapter properties for DC, if you set ip to : 192.168.1.1 and subnet: 255.255.255.0, what do you set gateway and preferred dns?

Comment: That's not going to matter if you don't have an Internet connection.  If you want the DC to act as a DNS server for the other clients, you'll want to advertise the DC's IP as the DNS server via DHCP.

Comment: When, I set up like this, windows 8 pro picked up ip 192.168.1.2 but, when I tried to join the domain, it throws error: "AD DC for the domain could not be contacted. Ensure the domain name is typed correctly"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19160/discussion-between-user3330840-and-heavyd).